# Hibernate calling INSERT on POST, but some data not there when I GET

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate

I am trying to use Hibernate to store two objects, Users (which have ID, name, and ImageURL) and Players (which have a User, Points, and FriendIDList).

For some reason, hibernate is correctly storing Users, and saying it is performing an INSERT into PLAYER, but when I try to retrieve the Player I just persisted (or any player) the collection is always empty.  Users come back correctly.  Tried em.flush() which didn't help, and tried creating a new Player with default constructor and doing em.persist on that but got same results.

Please help.  I really can't figure out what's wrong here.  This should be pretty basic.

Here is my WebService code for the POST on Players

```
@Path("/webService")
@RequestScoped
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public class MyWebService {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Path("/PlayerRequest/{id}/{name}/{imageURL}")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Player playerPOSTRequest(
            @PathParam("id") long id,
            @PathParam("name") String name,
            @PathParam("imageURL") String imageURL,
            ArrayList<String> JsonInput) {

        System.out.println("POST on a PlayerRequest for Player id: ["+ id + "]");

        User foundUser = null;
        foundUser = getUserByid(em, id);
        if(null == foundUser){
            User user = new User(id, name, imageURL);
            em.persist(user);
            foundUser = user;
        }

        Player foundPlayer = null;
        foundPlayer = getPlayerByid(em, id);

        if (null == foundPlayer) {
            Player player = new Player(foundUser);
            em.persist(player);
            em.flush(); //Try Flushing to see if that helps
            foundPlayer = player;
            Player newPlayer = new Player(); //See if default constructor is any different
            em.persist(newPlayer); //Try default constructor just to see
        } else {
            // RETURNING PLAYER
            System.out.println("Welcome back.  You are a current player.");
        }

        //Use JsonInput for stuff here

        System.out.println("Returning Player: " + foundPlayer);
        return foundPlayer;
    }// playerPOSTRequest

}//myWebService
```

Here is my Player class (less the get/setters)

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAYER")
public class Player implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    Long id = null;
    @Version
    private @Column(name = "version")
    int version = 0;

    public Player(){
    }

    public Player(User user) {
        this.PlayerInfo = user;
        this.Points = 100; //New users get 100 points to start with
        this.FriendList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private User PlayerInfo;

    @Column
    private long Points;

    @Column
    private ArrayList<Long> FriendList; 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [PlayerInfo_FBID=" + PlayerInfo.getFacebookID() + ", PlayerInfo_Name=" + PlayerInfo.getName() + "Points=" + Points + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is my User class less get/setters:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    Long id = null;
    @Version
    private @Column(name = "version")
    int version = 0;

    public User(){
    }

    public User(long id, String name, String imageURL){
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.ImageURL = imageURL;
    }

    @Column(name = "myId", unique = true)
    private long myId;

    @Column
    private String Name;

    @Column
    private String ImageURL;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + myId + ", Name=" + Name + "ImageURL=" + ImageURL + "]";
    }

}
```

When I run through this, here's the output I'm getting in the console, note the two INSER into PLAYER statements Hibernate is making (one is for the default constructor Player), but in the retrieves, I am able to get the user, but there are no existing players:

```
 POST on a PlayerRequest for Player ID: [36985]
 Hibernate: 
     select
         user0_.id as id12_,
         user0_.myID as myID12_,
         user0_.ImageURL as ImageURL12_,
         user0_.Name as Name12_,
         user0_.version as version12_ 
     from
         USER user0_ 
     where
         user0_.myID=?
 New User for PlayerInfo for Player request.  Adding User to the system.
 Hibernate: 
     call next value for hibernate_sequence
 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         USER
         (myID, ImageURL, Name, version, id) 
     values
         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 Hibernate: 
     select
         player0_.id as id13_,
         player0_.FriendList as FriendList13_,
         player0_.Points as Points13_,
         player0_.version as version13_ 
     from
         PLAYER player0_ cross 
     join
         USER user1_ 
     where
         player0_.id=user1_.id 
         and user1_.myID=?
 New Player request.  Adding Player to the system.
 Hibernate: 
     call next value for hibernate_sequence
 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         PLAYER
         (FriendList, Points, version, id) 
     values
         (?, ?, ?, ?)
 Hibernate: 
     call next value for hibernate_sequence
 Hibernate: 
     insert 
     into
         PLAYER
         (FriendList, Points, version, id) 
     values
         (?, ?, ?, ?)
 Returning Player: Player [PlayerInfo_ID=36985, PlayerInfo_Name=Joe Smith Points=100]

 GET on specific Player for User ID: [36985]
 Hibernate: 
     select
         player0_.id as id13_,
         player0_.FriendList as FriendList13_,
         player0_.Points as Points13_,
         player0_.version as version13_ 
     from
         PLAYER player0_ cross 
     join
         USER user1_ 
     where
         player0_.id=user1_.id 
         and user1_.myID=?
 Returning Player: null

 GET on All Players
 Hibernate: 
     select
         player0_.id as id13_,
         player0_.FriendList as FriendList13_,
         player0_.Points as Points13_,
         player0_.version as version13_ 
     from
         PLAYER player0_ cross 
     join
         USER user1_ 
     where
         player0_.id=user1_.id 
         and user1_.myID>?
 Returning List: []

 GET on specific User for User ID: [36985]
 Hibernate: 
     select
         user0_.id as id12_,
         user0_.myID as myID12_,
         user0_.ImageURL as ImageURL12_,
         user0_.Name as Name12_,
         user0_.version as version12_ 
     from
         USER user0_ 
     where
         user0_.myID=?
 Returning User: User [ID=36985, Name=Bob Smith ImageURL=www.myImage.com]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the Player's mapping annotations.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
```

The name given to the JoinColumn is the same given to the id (PK). Thus,  Hibernate is generating a wrong sql query, making a incorrect join between the two tables.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, changed name="myID" from User, now it works.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Very good! Its good to give vote if it was useful for you! ;)